# Geometric nodes - How to set/offset position of a specific edge's vertices

Tags: geometry-nodes, edges

How can I set/offset position of vertices of specific edge?
In the follow example given a plane with 9 faces. When setting a value in the node "Integer: Index of edge", the two vertices connected to the edge with that index should be offset up by 0.2.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

The edge is firstly recovered with two *Sample Index* nodes set in *Edge* domain, before its end vertices index is recovered with *Edge Vertices* nodes. It is to notice that the node *Set Position* is acting in *Point* domain.

[image: GN Graph]

**Resources:** [image]

Answer (score 1):

The follow solution adds a boolean flag attribute for each edge. When an edge's flag is True, its vertices are selected because of the flag value that is interpolated into the vertices domain in the selection process.

This solution has several advantages:

1. It has a smaller graph.
2. When wish edge index is out of range, no point will be offset.
3. It can be easily modified for selecting several edges by changing the logic inside the "Edges chooser" frame.
   [image]

For example, here is a modification for when we want edges 0,1,2,3 to be offset:
[image]